# Where to put styles for classes that are used across code base using sass 7-1 architecture

Tags: css, sass

I am refactoring a legacy web app and I am trying to use the [Sass 7-1](https://sass-guidelin.es/#the-7-1-pattern) architecture. The code has several 'global' class names i.e;

```
.flex-expand {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    position: relative;
}
.flex-scroll-area {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Where would classes that are used in many different files in the code base be placed?

Answer (score 1):

What about something like `abstracts/_extends.scss`?

```
.my-expandable-element {
   @extend .flex-expand;
   background: yellow;
   color: pink;
}
```